# JS Getting Wrong Value from ERB

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

So this is a *weird* one.  I'm doing AJAX stuff in my Rails 7 app and I have the following code in a partial:

```
<% if message.favorite %>
    <i onclick="unfavoriteMessage()" title="Click to remove this message from your favorites." class="pointer fa-solid fa-star h5 color-teal"></i>
<% else %>
    <i onclick="favoriteMessage()" title="Click to mark this message as a favorite." class="pointer fa-regular fa-star h5 color-teal"></i>
<% end %>
<%= message.id %>


<script defer>
    function favoriteMessage() {
      console.log("<%= j message.id %>")
      $.ajax({
        url: '/messages/<%= j message.id %>/favorite_message',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'script'
      });
    }

    function unfavoriteMessage() {
      console.log("<%= j message.id %>")
      $.ajax({
        url: '/messages/<%= j message.id %>/unfavorite_message',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'script'
      });
    }
</script>
```

The line of the HTML/ERB that says `<%= message.id %>` is rendered as 87 on the page.

However, the `console.log("<%= j message.id %>")` statements in the javascript (as well as the AJAX ones that actually matter) print out 53 in the console.

I tried with and without the escape javascript `j` but the behavior is the same either way.  Can anyone else see how this could be happening?  I am bamboozled.

Comment: Is that a partial? Are the multiple fav/unfavs on the page? Those js methods don't take the message id as a parameter and if they're multiple on page, with the same name, the last one takes precedence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the message id is not being derived from the particular message being clicked. If the `message` variable is being re-used for multiple messages on the page then it's not going to necessarily align with what the user chose.

That information can be contained in the [event object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) that's passed into the `onClick` function through the dom element, but will require adding that data to the element. Either through an `id` or a [data-property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) like `data-message-id`. That might look like this

```
<i id="<%= message.id %>" onclick="favoriteMessage()" title="Click to mark this message as a favorite." class="pointer fa-regular fa-star h5 color-teal"></i>
```

When that data's embedded in the element, we can access it in the click handler function. `event.currentTarget` will return the dom element where the handler is set. ([MDN for event#currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget))

Given the html snippet above, try something like this and let's see if it works ->

```
function favoriteMessage(event) {
  const messageId = event.currentTarget.id;
  $.ajax({
    url: `/messages/${messageId}/favorite_message`,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'script'
  });
}
```